# How to solve the problem of passing ID as name of file to be loaded as ID.html?

Tags: angularjs, ngroute, ng-view, pass-data

I have a lot of html pages, and decided to use their names (which are short and unique) as id, so when i want click to one row of table, the id (which is the name of file) is passed to templateURL. For example,

```
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when("/post/:id",
    {
        title: 'Disease',
        templateUrl : "/pages/posts/:id.html"
    })
```

For example, i have Treponema.html, HeartDisease.html, LungCancer.html etc in a list. When I click one, it should show its content on the right side of page, on which i have declared:

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

And when i click one listed item, i will take their id as the name (HearDisease, LungCancer) and put it in templateUrl.

```
<div id="HeartDisease" 
    onclick="window.location.href ='/post/'+this.id+'.html';>

     <p>HeartDisease.html</p>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the more appropriate for your use case will be to use [ng-include](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude). Look at the bottom of the page you have an example.

If you want to update the route in browser you can do it in your controller using the [$location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location) object.

Comment: But there are like a dozen cards, and links are opening on the right side. How can i do that with $location object?